# Customize with attribute field

Tags: acumatica

With the function PXCustomizeSelectorColumns, we can add usr field, I would like add attribute field ? But impossible to use this field, I have this error :

The type name 'COLOR_Attributes' does not exist in the type 'InventoryItem'

```
[PXCustomizeSelectorColumns(
typeof(PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem.inventoryCD),
typeof(PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem.descr),
typeof(PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem.COLOR_Attributes),
typeof(PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItemExt.usrCategorie))]
```

Xavier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because attribute field values do not exist within the standard tables.  All attributes are stored within a table called 'CSAnswers'  see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64037009/pull-attributes-from-stock-item-to-so-line-custom-field)

Comment: is there a way to do it anyway?

Comment: You would need to create a new PXSelector attribute with a Search that joins to CSAnswers  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74744520/how-can-i-perform-acumatica-bql-joins-in-pxselector